# Tensorflow / keras multi_gpu_model is not splitted to more than one gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I'm encountered the problem, that I can not successfully split my training batches to more than one GPU. If `multi_gpu_model` from `tensorflow.keras.utils` is used, tensorflow allocates the full memory on all available (for example 2) gpus, but only the first one (gpu[0]) is utilized to 100% if nvidia-smi is watched.

I'm using tensorflow 1.12 right now.

#### Test on single device

```
model = getSimpleCNN(... some parameters)

model .compile()
model .fit()
```

As expected, data is loaded by cpu and the model runs on gpu[0] with 97% - 100% gpu utilization:
[image]

#### Create a multi_gpu model

As described in the tensorflow api for multi_gpu_model [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model), the device scope for model definition is **not** changed.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

model = getSimpleCNN(... some parameters)
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2, cpu_merge=False)  # weights merge on GPU (recommended for NV-link)

parallel_model.compile()
parallel_model.fit()
```

As seen in the timeline, cpu now not only loads the data, but is doing some other calculations. Notice: the second gpu is nearly doing nothing:
[image]

#### The question

The effect even worsens as soon as four gpus are used. Utilization of the first one goes up to 100% but for the rest there are only short peeks.

Is there any solution to fix this? How to properly train on multiple gpus?

Is there any difference between `tensorflow.keras.utils` and `keras.utils` which causes the unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. 
In my case, the problem came from the use of a `build_model(... parameters)` function that returned the model. 
Be careful with your  `getSimpleCNN()` function, as I don't know what is in it my best advice is to build the model sequentially in your code without using this function.